# some google map markers not showing

Tags: google-maps-markers

Some of the markers on my map are not showing here at: http://touring-britain.heralded.co.uk/test/

I'm assuming Google has a limit as to the number of markers it displays before returning the default blue icon? I'm plugged directly into Google's kml for My Maps.

Any tips please?

Comment: Trying to load your page in chrome resulted in error and few warnings in developer's console: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined - have you tried fixing these first?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Anton. The errors are a side effect of protection software. Icons fail to show regardless of whether it's on or off. It's got me stumped. The page script is fine. The icons fail to show both with a localised Kml file and a direct to Google Kml file.